# Is there any online or free to download (for Windows 7) AVR simulators?

Tags: avr, simulation, attiny, debugging

I'm currently using CodeVision AVR to write a code. Let's say I have a compiled HEX file and I'd like to try it running on a virtual processor (ATtiny861A).

Google gives me some results but I'd appreciate if you will suggest me which one will be most free and easy to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx)? It has pretty good simulator.

Comment: I tried. Thanks! It was needed to rewrite all the code but luckily the code was pretty small. However I did not find any possibility to view output pins oscillograms. Do you know if I'm able to do it in Atmel Studio Simulator?